# Can't capture a group in regex

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to get the value of the attribute of value which can be any integer number including ones less than zero

```
val source = """...some noise .... <input type="hidden" name="myId" id="myId" value="1234"/> ...some noise ....""" // or value="-5678"/>

val regex = """<input type="hidden" name="myId" id="myId" value="([-?\\d+])"/>""".r
regex findAllIn source
```

And I get `scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator = empty iterator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't do what you think it does. It matches `-` or `?` or `\` or `d` or `+`. You have put everything into a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You should use:

```
(-?\d++)
```

As you are using the Scala tripe quote you don't need to double escape `\`.

Comment: @Grienders what do you mean? `[]` is a character group and works as such, you're just misusing it.

Comment: @Grienders; in regex `[]` denotes a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). This means that it defines a set of characters to match, so that pattern matches one of `-` or `?` or `d` or `+` as string literals. The escaped `d` does nothing in a character class, the double escape would match a literal `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
([-?\\d+])
```

to:

```
(-?\\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as what @M42 says (remove the square brackets), you want to remove one of the backslashes before the digit marker - remember that you are inside a "triple-quote" string - you don't need to escape backslashes:

```
(-?\d+)
```

Comment: This should be a comment on @M42's answer as it isn't a full standalone answer. If the answer it refers to is deleted it becomes useless.

Comment: Edited to briefly note what M42's answer says (the final snippet I give is still useable without that info, though). I'll bear it in mind for the future, though - thanks @BoristheSpider.